# Can I make Global Query Filters in Entity Framework 6? by OnModelCreating?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I try to make a global query. I know that this is possible in EF Core 2.0 however I need to do it using EF 6.

I try to do something like this in EF 6:
(IsDeleted is a property in my Class Cliente as boolean)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().HasQueryFilter(x => x.IsDeleted= false);
}
```

I will appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: EF6 does not provide out of the box global query filter capability. You can try the QueryFilter feature of the following 3rd party EF extension library [Entity Framework Plus](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus#entity-framework-plus)

Answer (score 4):

What I believe is that you want to implement soft-delete in your application. To apply a global query filter you can follow this approach too.

first of all, install `System.linq.Dynamic` Library using NuGet.

Then create one extension Method like:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereDeleted<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
{
    return source.Where("IsDeleted== false"); 
}
```

and then you can call other methods like this:

```
var client = db.Client.Include("whatever you need")
                      .WhereDeleted().Where(c => c.Age < 30);
```

Comment: I dont want to implement soft-delete, I did that parts already, I have wrote Global Query EF6. Please read question before answer.

Comment: I know. If you read the answer you will understand I did not show you how to implement soft delete. I show you how to implement a global query filter according to your question with an extension method. Please read the answer carefully.

Comment: What is a point of using System.Linq.Dynamic, why can't you just use .Where(e=>!e.IsDeleted);? And answer is not about the thing that Antonio asked. He asked how to achieve that globaly, like query filters in EF core 2.

Comment: Side note: instead of System.linq.Dynamic, you can apply an interface defining `IsDeleted` to the models that have this property/column. If using Database First, you can update the T4 file that generates your model to make the classes that have an IsDeleted property implement the interface.